# Popper translation of MUI Autocomplete Component issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I meet this issue using MUI Autocomplete component :(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8YDj.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzDox.png).
The popper sometimes appear on the left, sometimes on the right of the text input, there is my code :

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Autocomplete
    disablePortal={true}
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={technologies}
    sx={{ width: 300 }}
    className="nodrag"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="Technology"
        color="neutral"
        className="nodrag"
      />
    )}
  />
</ThemeProvider>
```

But it doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PopperComponent` prop as this:

```
const MyPopper = function (props) {
  return (<Popper {...props} style={{ width: 250 }} placement='bottom-start' />)
}
```

Then:

```
<Autocomplete PopperComponent={MyPopper}>
```

Comment: That seems to works expectedly, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, onChange or any event should be inside renderInput

```
<Autocomplete 
    freeSolo
    selectOnFocus
    handleHomeEndKeys
    id="combo-box-demo"
    className="nodrag"
    options={technologies}
    renderInput={
        (params) => (
            <TextField 
                {...params} 
                label="Enter Recipient's name"
                helperText="Please enter Recipient's name"
                value={recipient}
                onChange={({target}) => setRecipient(target.value)} />
        )} />
```